# Pass by name for macro arguments

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog, compiler-directives

For functions, we can use pass by name as below:

```
  function void xyz(string x,int y);
    $display(x,,y);
  endfunction

  initial begin
    xyz(.x("Hi"),.y(2));
  end
```

Now, I have a macro like below:

```
  `define XYZ(name,number) \
  int num; \
    num=number; \
    $display("%s %d",``name``,num);
```

It is invoked as `XYZ(hi,2)`. I would like to know how I can use pass by name in macros just as we do for functions.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how I can use pass by name in macros just as we
> do for functions.

You can not use pass-by-name for `define` macros like you do for functions.  You can not do something like this:

```
`XYZ(.name(hi),.number(2))
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 22.5.1 *`define*.  This shows the complete supported syntax for macros with several examples.

Answer (score 0):

A macro in verilog (also in c/c++) is a mechanism which allows simple **text** manipulations. It does text substitutions *before* any syntactic checking by the compiler. Arguments in macros are substituted with their actual values in text without any analysis. So, in your case the instance of **`XYZ(hi,2)** will just be expanded as

```
int num; \
    num=2; \
    $display("%s %d",hi,num);
```

This not what will work if you want to see the *name* printed with $display. However, there are ways to *stingize* arguments. For that you need to change the definition syntax to the following:

```
`define XYZ(name,number) \
  int num; \
    num=number; \
    $display("%s %d",`"name`",num);  // `"name" should also work
`XYZ(hi,2)

--->
 int num;
    num=2;
    $display("%s %d","hi",num);
```